# Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'toString' of undefined

Tags: javascript, html

Why is my code not working?
Chrome gives me the following error: `Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'toString' of undefined`.

It works with 1,2,3,4,6,7,8,9 but does not work with 5,10,15,...

Please help me out.

Here is my javascript code:

```
<code><script>
function mmCal(val) {
    var a, b, c, d, e, f, g, h, i;
    a = val * 25.4;
    b = a.toString().split(".")[0];
    c = a.toString().split(".")[1];
    d = c.toString().substr(0, 1);
    e = +b + +1;
    f = b;

    if (d>5) {
        document.getElementById("txtt").value = e;
    } else {
        document.getElementById("txtt").value = f;
    }
}
</script></code>
```

Here is my html:

```
<code><input type="text" id="txt" value="" onchange="mmCal(this.value)"></code>
<code><input type="text" id="txtt" value=""></code>
```

Comment: `5 * 25.4` is `127`.  You are trying to split that on `split(".")`.  That gives you `[127]`, which doesn't have an index `[1]`, so `c` is undefined.  The problem is the same for `10` and `15`.

Comment: @RocketHazmat That's the **answer**...

Comment: @OlehPrypin - The answer should probably include Math.round. Rocket's comment was more of the cause.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As Sebnukem says

> It doesn't work when a is an integer because there's no period to
>   split your string, and that happens with multiples of 5.

But you could have a trick so use `a % 1 != 0` to know wherther the value is a decimal see the code below:

```
function mmCal(val) {
var a, b, c, d, e, f, g, h, i;
a = val * 25.4;
    if(a % 1 != 0){
    b = a.toString().split(".")[0];
    c = a.toString().split(".")[1];
    }
    else{
    b = a.toString();
    c = a.toString();
    }
d = c.toString().substr(0, 1);
e = +b + +1;
f = b;
if (d>5) {
document.getElementById("txtt").value = e;
} else {
document.getElementById("txtt").value = f;
}
}
```

That could you help you.

[LIVE DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/sngybLju/1/)

Answer (score 1):

It doesn't work when `a` is an integer because there's no period to split your string, and that happens with multiples of 5.

Answer (score 0):

Strange way of rounding a number to an integer :-)

You are converting inches to millimeters, and then rounding that to an integer, right?

Why not use 'toFixed()' on the number? See: [Number.prototype.toFixed()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Number/toFixed)

I mean:

```
function mmCal(val) {
    var a, rounded;
    a = val * 25.4;
    rounded = a.toFixed();
    document.getElementById("txtt").value = rounded;
}
```

(you may also use "toFixed(0)" for the explicit precision).